# how to get label of amchart stacked bar on clickgraphitem

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to get Label on graph click event,i am using amchart stacked bar.

- Example :

  - When I click on bar 1 **graph 1 of category 1 : 8**, I get **graph 1**.
  - When I click on bar 1 **graph 2 of category 1 : 5**, I get **graph 2**.

Below is the link of chart and also I added my code: [Stackbar chart](https://live.amcharts.com/new/edit/).

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", DashBoardClick); 
    function DashBoardClick(event) {
    alert(event.item.category);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant the title of the graph, you can access it through the `graph` object in the event argument as noted in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#clickGraphItem) and then access the graph's [`title`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#title) property, i.e. `event.graph.title`.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
    {
      "type": "serial",
      "categoryField": "category",
      "startDuration": 1,
      "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start"
      },
      "trendLines": [],
      "graphs": [
        {
          "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
          "fillAlphas": 1,
          "id": "AmGraph-1",
          "title": "graph 1",
          "type": "column",
          "valueField": "column-1"
        },
        {
          "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
          "fillAlphas": 1,
          "id": "AmGraph-2",
          "title": "graph 2",
          "type": "column",
          "valueField": "column-2"
        }
      ],
      "guides": [],
      "valueAxes": [
        {
          "id": "ValueAxis-1",
          "stackType": "regular",
          "title": "Axis title"
        }
      ],
      "allLabels": [],
      "balloon": {},
      "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "useGraphSettings": true
      },
      "titles": [
        {
          "id": "Title-1",
          "size": 15,
          "text": "Chart Title"
        }
      ],
      "dataProvider": [
        {
          "category": "category 1",
          "column-1": 8,
          "column-2": 5
        },
        {
          "category": "category 2",
          "column-1": 6,
          "column-2": 7
        },
        {
          "category": "category 3",
          "column-1": 2,
          "column-2": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  );

chart.addListener('clickGraphItem', function(event) {
  alert(event.graph.title);
})
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
```